# Need help calling array to post in Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to get my array to read from a xml file and post into html.(My assignment is to get ajax to run from xml) My script so far is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlDoc;
    var xmlhttp;



    function loadinfo()
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = readinfo;
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "Info.xml", true);
            xmlhttp.send();


        }


    function readinfo()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.informationXML;

            var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info")



            var var1 = items[0].getAttribute("campus-email", "campus-phone", "online-email", "online-phone");

        }
    }
```

I made sure I added this to the body > body onload="loadinfo();"

Comment: Tried using the document.getElementById but that never works too

Comment: There's no `informationXML` property in `xmlhttp`. Are you thinking of `responseXML`?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest for all the properties of XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.informationXML;
```

should be:

```
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, May you guide me the way to pull my array into html please? Can't find any info

Comment: What does _pull my array into html_ mean? You can't have arrays in HTML, just HTML tags and text.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to loop over all the XML elements, and construct DOM elements from them.